# When lac can be written as lakh or lacs?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

In India, **100 thousand** is sometime referred to as **1 lakh**, while sometime as **1 lac**. I am not sure if **lakh** is correct. Sometimes, I find the people writing more than one **lac** (or **lakh**) as **lacs** (or **lacs**). For example: The seller has received a sum of Rupees three lacs seventy-six thousands five hundreds thirty-six. I am not sure if **lac**, **thousand** and **hundred** were correctly converted as **lacs**, **thousands** and **hundreds**, in the instant example. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: The OED has an entry under *lakh*. It is a word of Hindu origin, but it is said to be part of *Indian English*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As WS2 has pointed out correctly, *lakh* is part of Indian English. Therefore, the cited example must read

> The seller has received a sum of Rupees three *lakh* seventy-six *thousand* five *hundred and* thirty-six

When quoting sum (or any currency values) in written words, pluralization of units(thousands , hundreds) is not acceptable since we are expressing the numerals *as is* in written form (We know the exact value).

Thousands, lakhs cab be used in generic sentences. For example,

> Thousands of people were affected in the recent Chennai floods.

or

> Lakhs of devotees visit Tirupati everyday